# How many cyclic subgroups are in $\Bbb Z_8\oplus\Bbb Z_4\oplus\Bbb Z_2$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, p-groups

Consider the group $\Bbb Z_8\oplus\Bbb Z_4\oplus\Bbb Z_2$. How many nontrivial cyclic groups does it contain?
I know the answer is $27$, so my question is how to get it effectively.
I was trying to solve it by solving the system of modular equations:
find all n for which there are such a, b, c in $\Bbb Z_8, \Bbb Z_4, \Bbb Z_2$ respectively that satisfy:

$\\
an (mod 8)=0,\\
 bn (mod 4)=0,\\
 cn (mod 2)=0,\\$

but I'm not sure if it is really effective.
Also it would be great to see if this task is solvable by using Young tableaux.

Comment: Count the number of elements of order $1$; then order $2$; then order $4$; then order $8$. Divide each by an appropriate quantity. Add up the results.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought there is no difference between two cyclic groups of the same order, but I’m not sure what the question means. I was trying to think of it like this: there are subgroups of orders 2, 4, 8 for example. So we have at least 3 cyclic subgroups. What I am trying to say is that I don’t see any reason to count the numbers of orders.

Comment: @Bary Two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic, but they do not contain the same elements and so are not the same. If they are subgroups, also might have difference relationships with the main group.

Comment: The question is not asking how many **isomorphism types** of cyclic subgroups the group has; that would be four and just four. It is asking how many cyclic subgroups it has. For instance, the subgroups generated by $(0,0,1)$, $(0,2,0)$, and $(4,0,0)$ are each cyclic subgroups of order $2$ (and hence isomorphic), but they are *distinct* subgroups that must be counted separately.

Comment: PS The subject line is not part of the post. Put the question in thebody of the post. You don't start letters at the envelop, and your post does not start in the subject line.

Comment: @Saad: Why is this closed?

Comment: @amWhy: Why did you vote  to close? Closing  without leaving comment is rude.

Comment: @markvs How did you manage to read the closers' names without reading the explanation box above it?

Comment: Closers names are on top:  John Omielan, Ѕааԁ, Shaun, Bulbasaur, amWhy. Saad and amWhy are closing all questions which have my answer. Hence I asked why don't they leave comments. In this case "lack of content" is far from obvious: the Q even contains the correct numerical value of the answer.

Comment: @markvs Really? hm, on my screen they are beneath the rationale... I believe you if you say so though.

Comment: `are closing all questions which have my answer.` Hm, double check to see if those questions are of a similar quality. Sometimes it is tempting to answer them since they are often easy, but strictly speaking they should not be answered until they satisfy the guidelines. If you really believe it is a matter of targeting you and not actually them being consistent about post quality, you can always flag with your concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $28$. Let $1,1,1$ be the additive generators of the three direct factors. Then every cyclic subgroup is generated by a triple $(m, n, k)$ where $m\in\{0,...,7\}, n\in\{0,1,2,3\}, k\in\{0,1\}$. If $gcd(m,8)=1$, then some odd multiple of  $(m,n, k)$ is of the form $(1,n',k')$ and is generating the same cyclic subgroup of order $8$. So we can assume that in this case $m=1$. The choices for $n,k$ are arbitrary: $4\cdot 2=8$ cyclic subgroups of order $8$.

If $gcd(m,8)=2$, then some odd multiple of $(m,n,k)$ is of the form $(2,n',k')$ and is generating the same cyclic subgroup of order $4$. So we can assume that in this case $m=2$. The choices for $n,k$ are again arbitrary, $8$ cyclic subgroups of that form.

If $m=4$, then we can assume that $n=1,2$ or $0$,arbitrary choices of $k$ give different cyclic subgroups, $6$ cyclic subgroups of this form.

Finally if $m=0$, we have to look at $n$. If $n=1,3$ we can assume $n=1$, we have $2$ such cyclic subgroups generated by $(0,1,1),(0,1,0)$. If $n=2$ we again have two cyclic subgroups, $k=0,1$, generated by $(0,2,0), (0,2,1)$ and if $n=0$, we have two cyclic subgroups, one of which is trivial. So altogether there are $8*2+6*2=28$ cyclic subgroups including the trivial one.

Comment: You may have double-counted the last case. $k=0,n=3$ generates the same cycles as $k=0,n=1$, appearing in different order, so the correct count is $8×3+2×\color{blue}{2}=28$ including the trivial group.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, there is one of order $1$, $7$ of order $2$, $12$ of order $4$, and $8$ of order $8$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: If $m=0$, and $n=1,3$, then we can assume $n=1$ and we have two cyclic subgroup generated by $(0,1,0),(0,1,1)$. Isn't it right?If $m=0,n=2$, then we have two cyclic subgroups generated by $(0,2,0),(0,2,1)$ and if $m=0,n=0$ we have 2 cyclic subgroups generated by $(0,0,1),(0,0,0)$. Which cyclic subgroup is counted twice?

Comment: I found and corrected the error, in the case $m=4$ there are $6$ choices, not $8$ because in this case $n=1,2$ or $0$ (the case $n=3$ is equivalent to $n=1$). The total number is $28$.